# run update/delete query when mysql server starts/restarts?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I am developing an app based on PHP/Laravel.There is a scenario where I have to insert large number of data in MySQL table,it takes ~1-2 minutes to complete insert query once submitted by user.I wanted to bypass another insert query while previous is still in progress.

So I made a `log` table, where value of `0` is inserted on `is_completed` field before the bulk insert starts on another table and when the loop of bulk insert completes, I have trrigered another query that updates `1` on `is_completed` field of `log` table.

This way I can check if `is_complete` flag is set to `1` to allow next request by user else just bypass the query.I have used transaction for bulk insert and I clear log when handling exceptions if it occurs any.

Now the problem occurs if the server restarts while bulk insert is in progress in that case the `is_complete` flag is set to `0` on log table.If so user won't be able to request to insert data until the next day.

Is there provision of any sorts of automation on MYSQL, so that when the DB server just starts we can run query ? If so I will trigger query to clear log table.Please can any one tell me how to do that or suggest me better solution,regarding my scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `init_file` server option to run SQL statements on server startup.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file